# Date format conversion using Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am having a date/time value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format such as as **2010-07-26T11:37:52Z**.

I want date in **26-jul-2010 (dd-mon-yyyy)** format. How do I do it?

Comment: Modern way: `OffsetDateTime.parse("2010-07-26T11:37:52Z").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu"))`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Construct two SimpleDateFormat objects. The first you parse() the value from into a Date object, the second you use to turn the Date object back into a string, e.g.

```
try {
  DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
  DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
  return df2.format(df1.parse(input));
}
catch (ParseException e) {
  return null;
}
```

Parsing can throw a ParseException so you would need to catch and handle that.

Comment: its working perfectly....eally thankful to you for your quick answer, made my life

Comment: it’s really incorrect, though it may give you the result you want. `Z` means offset zero, but you parse the date-time into your JVM’s time zone, giving an incorrect time. If you don’t use the time-of-day, you will in many case get the desired output, depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: As, Ole V.V. commented, this **Answer is incorrect**. The single-quotes around the `Z` means "ignore this text". But that text is valuable information! The `Z` is pronounced “Zulu” and means an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, or UTC itself. So this Answer is throwing away vital information, for no good reason. Furthermore, this Answers fails to address the vital issue of time zone. That moment in UTC might be another date, "tomorrow", if viewed in Tokyo, or "yesterday" if viewed in Montréal. See [the correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56760402/642706) by Ole V.V.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using Java's `SimpleDateFormat` class?  It is included with the android SDK:  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

I am providing the modern answer. No one should use `SimpleDateFormat` anymore.

### java.time

Parsing text.

```
    String dateTimeValue = "2010-07-26T11:37:52Z";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeValue);
```

Generating text.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "dd-MMM-uuuu", 
            Locale.forLanguageTag("pt-BR")
        );
    String wantedFormattedDate = dateTime.format(dateFormatter);
```

Output:

```
    System.out.println(wantedFormattedDate);
```

> 26-jul-2010

The month abbreviation in the output depends on the locale provided (Brazilian Portuguese in my example).

I am exploiting the fact that your date-time is in ISO 8601 format, the format that the classes of java.time parse (and also print) as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

Avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class used in the other answers. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated.

Normally you would not want to convert a date and time from a string in one format to a string in a different format. In your program keep date and time as a date-time object, for example `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`. Only when you need to give out a string, format your date into one.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)