# Android - datetime field hell! - well, seems like it anyway! :)

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I am storing values from Calendar.getTime() in my SQLite database field called 'Created' when new records are inserted..

The field is 'datetime' and it stores values in this format : EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy.

My app has 2 datepickers so you can select a start and end date/time to create a range - all I need to do is run a query to return records which were created within this timespan but it is giving me a major headache!

My query looks like this :

```
public Cursor GetAllByDateRange(Date dtStart, Date dtEnd) {

    return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { 
            KEY_id, KEY_CREATED, KEY_VALUE, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_ISEXPENSE}, 
            KEY_CREATED + " BETWEEN '" + dtStart + "' AND '" + dtEnd + "'",
            null, null, null, KEY_CREATED + " DESC");
}
```

I think I understand the problem but not how to resolve it, I believe this approach will not work because SQLite stores dates in String format (if this is true I'm not sure why they even have a Date' type!), so they get compared as Strings rather than dates..

It appears my options are limited because I need to record time as well as the date, having spent most of today trawling the web I am at a complete loss - can anyone suggest how I can move forward?

Thanks!

Comment: Dear @Mike you can convert your date into specific format as you mentioned in your question before pass it to query, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778202/android-date-format-conversion) how to convert date into specific format.

Comment: There is another approach you can save your date and time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, store your dates as integers in the datbase, storing the milliseconds value from date.toTime(). It's then much easier to instantiate a date object from new Date(milliseconds) and you can then format the output according to the locale.

Comment: Yep I had this same problem before, and storing as integers (milliseconds) solved it. You can then do compares in your queries. When you pull it out, convert it to human readable date.