# Converting Timestamp value in a prticular Date Time Format

Tags: android

I have a problem that I have a timestamp value which is coming from JSON parsing, I am converting that timastamp in Date Time Format which is desired, all is working fine but month always return 1 in any case. means If timestamp contains aug month but it returns only 1 for any month. I don't know how to resolve this. Please suggest me the solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
public String create_datestring(String timestring){
        try{
                final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timestring));
                timestring = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "/" +String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/" + String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            timestring = "9/23/2011";--->timestring always returns 1 for month.
        }
```

Comment: What are you doing? You just need to parse the timeString in your desired format. Use SimpleDateFormat class.

Comment: means? Please explain your answer.

Comment: Just check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3778202/379693

Comment: did you mean? What is the timestamp value? Time stamp value is a Long Integer Value which have to be converted in a Date Time Format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private String getDate(String timeStampStr){

    try{
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date netDate = (new Date(Long.parseLong(timeStampStr)));
        return sdf.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        return dateInStr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one It may gives you satisfied output.

```
String DATE_FORMAT="hh:mm aa dd MMMM yyyy";
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        private String getDate(long time) {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).format(time * 1000);
        }
```