# How to make Facebook Friends Birthday Custom in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have made an app in which i am getting list of all my **Facebook friends birthdays**, something like this:

> Ricky

02/13/1990

but now i want to show something like this:

> Ricky

February 13, 1990

Code:-

**MyAdapter.java**

```
 TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
    name.setText(friend.getName());

    TextView bday = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label2);
    if (!friend.getBday().trim().equals("")) {
        bday.setText(friend.getBday());
    } else {
        bday.setText("Not Mentioned");
    }

    return v;
}
```

**MyFacebook.java**

```
  public void init(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
    mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    isReady = false;
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    mFacebook.authorize(main, new String[] { "publish_stream",
            "friends_birthday" }, new MyAuthorizeListener());
}

// ref- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/
public Report reLoadAllFriends() {
    if (!isReady) {
        Log.v(TAG, "myfacebook.reloadallfriends Not ready yet!");
        return new Report(false, "Not ready yet!");
    }

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "id,name,birthday,picture");
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", params, new MyRequestListener(
            RequestType.FRIEND_LIST));

    Log.v(TAG, "myfacebook.reloadallfriends Fetch started.");
    return new Report(true, "Fetch started");
}

public List<MyFriend> getAllFriends() {
    return getFilteredFriends(null);
}

public List<MyFriend> getFilteredFriends(com.january.floogoo.Filter week) {
    return Main.db.getFriendsFilteredBy(week);
}

public List<Map<String, String>> getAllFriendsAsMap() {
    return getFilteredFriendsAsMap(null);
}

 public List<Map<String, String>> getFilteredFriendsAsMap(Filter filterBy) {
    List<MyFriend> friendList = Main.db.getFriendsFilteredBy(filterBy);

    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (MyFriend friend : friendList) {
        list.add(friend.getMap());
    }
    return list;
}

public void post(String receiver, String message) {
    if (isReady) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", message);

        mAsyncRunner.request(receiver + "/feed", params, "POST",
                new MyRequestListener(RequestType.FEED_POST));
    }
}

class MyAuthorizeListener extends BaseDialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Authorization successfull");
        isReady = true;
        main.loadContents();
    }
}

class MyRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
    private RequestType type;

    public MyRequestListener(RequestType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void onComplete(final String response) {
        try {
            switch (type) {
            case FRIEND_LIST:
                 Log.d(TAG, "myfacebook.friendlist Response: "
                 + response.toString());
                myFriends.clear();
    JSONArray jarr = Util.parseJson(response).getJSONArray(
                        "data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String fbID = json.getString("id");
                    String name = json.getString("name");
                    String bday = json.optString("birthday");
                    String pic = json.getString("picture");

                myFriends.add(new MyFriend(fbID, name, bday, pic));
                }
                main.notifyMain(Note.FRIENDLIST_RELOADED); 
                break;
            case FEED_POST:
                Log.d(TAG, "myfacebook.feedpost Response: "
                        + response.toString());
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFriend.java**

```
    public class MyFriend {
private String fbID = " ";
private String name = " ";
private String bday = " "; // can be missing, be in form of mm/dd or
                           // mm/dd/yyyy
private String pic = " ";
private String bdayMessage = " ";
private boolean isAutoPost = false;

public MyFriend() {

}
```

Comment: parse the date into a date object, and then format the date into the string you would like it to show.

Comment: @meh i have tried that several times, show me some code what i need to write in my code, then i will do change in my program where i am not getting what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SimpleDateFormate` to formate your date:

```
if (!friend.getBday().trim().equals("")) {
    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");   
    Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(bday.setText(friend.getBday()));   
    SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");   
    String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
    bday.setText(newDateStr); // <--------- Set your date after formatting.
} else {
    bday.setText("Not Mentioned");
}
```

Comment: I have tried buddy like in my case i am writing this---                 TextView bday = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label2);
   
  if (!friend.getBday().trim().equals("")) {
   bday.setText(friend.getBday());
  } else {
   bday.setText("Not Mentioned");
  }
 and getting output in form of : 02/25/1991, so change my code what i have to write to achieve that target like: February 25, 1991

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [Date format conversion using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778202/android-date-format-conversion)

you need some thing like this:

```
try {
  DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
  return df2.format(df1.parse(input));
}
catch (ParseException e) {
  return null;
}
```

========================================
Try this :

```
    TextView bday = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label2);
    if (!friend.getBday().trim().equals("")) {

        try {
            // If this line is in loop you can declare thie two SimpleDateFormat //before loop
            SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");

            bday.setText(df2.format(df1.parse(friend.getBday().trim())));

            Log.i("Nimish", df2.format(df1.parse("12/13/1990")));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            bday.setText("Not Mentioned");
            Log.i("Nimish", "" + e);
        }

    } else {
        bday.setText("Not Mentioned");
    }
```

Output :
01-04 17:51:29.299: I/Nimish(5042): December 13, 1990

Comment: like in my case i am writing this---                 TextView bday = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label2);
   
  if (!friend.getBday().trim().equals("")) {
   bday.setText(friend.getBday());
  } else {
   bday.setText("Not Mentioned");
  }
 and getting output in form of : 02/25/1991, so change my code what i have to write to achieve that target like: February 25, 1991