# How to split date and time got from mysql in android

Tags: android, datetime, split

I getting date from MySql, in the format of "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" I just want to split the date and time, show date separately and time also. Time like hh:mm, date like yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormatter

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: you'd rather get the date as a long, if you have the hand on the mysql part.

Comment: you don't have a timezone ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - date format conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778202/android-date-format-conversion)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You Can also use StringTokenizer class,  it allows you to break string into tokens. You can specify characters that will separate tokens.

Example:

```
String date = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss";
StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(date);

String date = tk.nextToken();  // <---  yyyy-mm-dd
String time = tk.nextToken();  // <---  hh:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you will me using it, but you can do a `String.split(" ")` to get both parts or parse it as a Date/Calendar and extract the date and time.

For example:

```
String d = "2013-05-11 13:59:50";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");

try {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(d));

    Log.d("DEBUG", "year:" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    //...
} catch (ParseException e) {
}
```

**Also**, as njzk2 said: other way would be to store a long value in your table so you can extract it directly to a Date/calendar

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(yourDbLongValue);
```

Comment: not very clean. SimpleDateFormat is much clearer and maintanable.

Comment: Yep, thats what i meant with the Date/Calendar stuff. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Try following code.

```
String dateValue = "2013-05-11 13:59:50";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");

Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.parse(dateValue);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String sa = timeFormatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the results from MySQL are controllable, you can do `select DATE(my_date_time) FROM my_table;` this will give you only the date. If not, then I guess if you look at the date as a string you can substring (Split) it and get the first 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

use the substring method

```
startdate=start_time.substring(0, 10); 
starttime=start_time.substring(11, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String fullDate = format.format(mDate.getTime());
date = fullDate.substring(0, fullDate.indexOf(" ");
time = fullDate.substring(fullDate.indexOf(" " + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

RoadBean roadBean = new RoadBean();

StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(jsonObject.getString("datetime"));

String split_date = tk.nextToken();

String split_time = tk.nextToken();

roadBean.setDate(split_date);

roadBean.setTime(split_time);

mRoadBeanList.add(roadBean);

Answer (score 0):

Split time as hour, minute and second.

```
String timeSpent="12:30:10";
String[] seperatedTime= timeSpent.split(":");
int hours = Integer.parseInt(seperatedTime[0]);
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(seperatedTime[1]);
int seconds = Integer.parseInt(seperatedTime[2]);
int duration = 3600 * hours + 60 * minutes + seconds;
```