# Formatting a string to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: java, date

I have the string `Thu Nov 12 00:00:00 GMT 2015` which is `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy`.

I want to convert this string into a string with the format of `dd/MM/yyyy`, or in this case `12/11/2015`.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out, in whatever language you happen to be attempting this in.

Comment: Fair point, meant to tag Java

Comment: There are lots of resources available via a Google search. Try searching for "java date format" or "java datetime format" and you should find a lot of examples and data format options.

Comment: @rghome, technically, OP has a string to string conversion issue.

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778202/date-format-conversion-using-java. Or one of dozens of other similar questions.

Comment: This is trivial to find with Google. Seriously.

Comment: @rghome, no doubt this is a duplicate, how about this **[one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097256/how-to-convert-mon-jun-18-000000-ist-2012-to-18-06-2012)**

Comment: @VivinPaliath To be honest, 99% of questions on SO is trivial to find with google.

Comment: @Divers ... and most of them point to here.

Comment: @Divers True! But *especially* for questions like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sTo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String result = sTo.format(sFrom.parse("Thu Nov 12 00:00:00 GMT 2015"));
```